# Return vertical offset of element with jQuery

Tags: jquery

This variable returns the offset of the element from the document. It returns a left and top value for the horizontal and vertical offset.

```
var myVar = $("#myDiv").offset();
```

How can I just return the vertical offset? The following returns an error:

```
var myVar = $("#myDiv").offset.top();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing mistake with [offset](http://api.jquery.com/offset/), so use like this:

```
var myVar = $("#myDiv").offset().top;
```

Comment: I might be just bitching right now, but how is this better than my answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
var myVar = $("#myDiv").offset().top;
```

This should work

Answer (score 0):

You have missed `()` in offset,

```
 var offset = $( '#myDiv' ).offset();
 console.log(offset.left + ", " + offset.top);
```